# Send message to remote MSMQ using Nservicebus

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am able to add messages to local MSMQ using nservicebus by below code

```
var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.Msmq.Simple");
    var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();

    endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
    endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
    endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();

    var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var myMessage = new MyMessage();
        await endpointInstance.SendLocal(myMessage)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But I read at some places that I can send messages to remote MSMQ, see code below

```
FormatName:Direct=TCP:100.100.100.12\\private$\\remoteTxn
```

But I am not able to figure how to send to Remote MSMQ using Nservicebus. Anyone can pitch here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SendLocal` you need to either use `Send` in case of a command or `Publish` in case of an event.

Using `Send` means you need to have message routing in place, as that determines what is the destination of the message. Routing could be defined [using code](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing#command-routing), or other means like [external files](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/file-based-routing) which makes it easier for dev/ops to change the routes at runtime in future.

An overload of the `Send` method also accepts a destination endpoint, but it is recommended to not mix concerns and keep the routing code separate (hence not using the overload with the destination). More info [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/routing).

Comment: Thanks Hadi for the direction I need to look into. I have a windows container with MSMQ installed and an endpoint is running on that container which adds message to MSMQ installed on the windows container. I need to send that message to HOST MSMQ instead and am not getting any code or help on this. Do you have any code which can do that? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest contacting our support by sending an email to support at particular dot net. You are focusing on way too lower level (MSMQ/Host level) where NSB abstraction is about endpoints.